# why typeof this.varForm.controls.Option.value is always returing string even if the user entered number

Tags: angular

entered input for control option            :  abcd
this.varForm.controls.Option.value  returns : "abcd"
typeof this.varForm.controls.Option.value   :  string

entered input for control option             :1233
this.varForm.controls.Option.value  returns  :"123123"
typeof this.varForm.controls.Option.value     :  string

i want the typeof the input entered using form contol name but it always returning string.

Comment: The ```Option``` field input type is text or number??

Comment: its not specific to number or string .....user can enter anything .Can we  able to find out what type he has entered using form control name in angular forms?

Comment: The default type of input is text (if you don't specify a type), which means it will considered as string no matter what user entered. specify the type as number and check.
https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#input.text